# Best way to start reliable background downloads immediately on iOS 7

Tags: cocoa-touch, networking, ios7, concurrency, xamarin.ios

I am a bit confused about the different options to handle file downloads on iOS.

- I want to be able to handle > 2.000 downloads a time, so some kind of parallelism would be nice
- I want a download to be started immediately when fired
- I want a download not to be paused or stopped when sending the app to the background

The concrete scenario is a bunch of downloads which are made initially after the user logs into the application. Here I have to download that many files which are mainly small images.

Currently I am using `NSURLSessionConfiguration`'s `defaultSessionConfiguration`, but going this way the downloads get paused when the user suspends the app (which is likely as the full process needs some minutes).

`NSURLSessionConfiguration` `backgroundSessionConfiguration` seems to be the better way to go, but I am seeing delays of up to 20-30 seconds before anything happens after initializing. That's propably okay for some scenarios, but not for mine.

So is there a way to get a workaround to that delay issue? Otherwise I will propably go the "old way" and just download the files in background threads on my own with the 10 minutes limitation.

Comment: Please see the guidance in the Objective-C tag wiki excerpt: only questions _about the language itself_ or _containing ObjC code_ should use the tag.